# iterating a list of csv's in pandas returning a PermissionError

Tags: python, pandas, windows, csv, jupyter

I am trying to iterate through a folder of csv files, but i get stopped by a PermissionError,
The weird thing is the folder is supposed to be accesable as i am logged in on a Administrator account on my windows 10 machine and the files are in a new folder with security set to be able to read and write.
I fear it is a some stupid window permission problem i have spend to many hours trying to solve this :).

```
import pandas as pd
import os
 
raw_data_path = 'C:\\Users\\jeppe\\data\\'   

filenames = os.listdir(raw_data_path)

for file in filenames:
    df = pd.read_csv(f'{raw_data_path}{file}')
    
    ..append some code



PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_12388/436724791.py in <module>
----> 1 pd.read_csv(Path(f'{raw_data_path}{file}'))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    309                     stacklevel=stacklevel,
    310                 )
--> 311             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    312 
    313         return wrapper

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, encoding_errors, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, on_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision, storage_options)
    584     kwds.update(kwds_defaults)
    585 
--> 586     return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    587 
    588 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    480 
    481     # Create the parser.
--> 482     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    483 
    484     if chunksize or iterator:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    809             self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
    810 
--> 811         self._engine = self._make_engine(self.engine)
    812 
    813     def close(self):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1038             )
   1039         # error: Too many arguments for "ParserBase"
-> 1040         return mapping[engine](self.f, **self.options)  # type: ignore[call-arg]
   1041 
   1042     def _failover_to_python(self):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\c_parser_wrapper.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
     49 
     50         # open handles
---> 51         self._open_handles(src, kwds)
     52         assert self.handles is not None
     53 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\base_parser.py in _open_handles(self, src, kwds)
    220         Let the readers open IOHandles after they are done with their potential raises.
    221         """
--> 222         self.handles = get_handle(
    223             src,
    224             "r",

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py in get_handle(path_or_buf, mode, encoding, compression, memory_map, is_text, errors, storage_options)
    700         if ioargs.encoding and "b" not in ioargs.mode:
    701             # Encoding
--> 702             handle = open(
    703                 handle,
    704                 ioargs.mode,

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\jeppe\\bot\\data\\.ipynb_checkpoints'


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6a3q0.png
```

Comment: it might just be that specific file that has a permission issue. Looks like some jupyter related config file. You can try filtering out what you're actually reading e.g. avoid files that start with '.', and see if that helps

Comment: you know this was my first post on stack overflow! and was so helpfull to get some fresh eyes on it! Thanks alot i filtered out all files starting with a dot and it worked!

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried moving the .csv folder in the same folder as your Jupyer notbook .ipynb file, refreshing/reloading the kernel and the folder name directly ?

Comment: no did not try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It is nececary to exclude the .ipynb_checkpoints file, this can be achived by this simple for loop**

```
 for file in filenames:
    if not file.startswith("."):
       df = pd.read_csv(f'{raw_data_path}{file}')
```